# I'm using DaisyUi navbar but it doesnt open dropdown like it does on DaisyUi website Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm trying to work with daisy and tailwind not changing much with javascript but can't figure out why it doesn't behave same as on daisyUi web page.. when I click Parent on my script it just doesn't open dropdown menu, it adds open="" to details tag like it does on their page but except arrow rotating nothing else happens.

```
<div className="navbar bg-base-100">
  <div className="navbar-start">
    <div className="dropdown">
      <label tabIndex={0} className="btn btn-ghost lg:hidden">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16" /></svg>
      </label>
      <ul tabIndex={0} className="menu menu-sm dropdown-content mt-3 z-[1] p-2 shadow bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52">
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li>
          <a>Parent</a>
          <ul className="p-2">
            <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <a className="btn btn-ghost normal-case text-xl">daisyUI</a>
  </div>
  <div className="navbar-center hidden lg:flex">
    <ul className="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
      <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
      <li tabIndex={0}>
        <details>
          <summary>Parent</summary>
          <ul className="p-2">
            <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </li>
      <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div className="navbar-end">
    <a className="btn">Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's weird that when i put same code in my .tsx file it doesn't work.. any ideas?
tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
};
```

package.json

```
  "name": "lion_lazuli_travel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.5.8",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "eslint": "8.48.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "formik": "^2.4.3",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "daisyui": "^3.6.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.29",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine on mine, share your tailwind config and package/log

Comment: Idk how but i fixed it :D anyway thx for your time

Comment: @Khekaes maybe post how you did it and mark as answered when you can?

Answer (score 1):

1st: You must have updated dependencies,
`npm i -D daisyui@latest`

2nd:
Make your ul or un ordered list under your details tag is absolute.

```html
<details>
     <summary>Parent</summary>
          <ul className="p-2 absolute z-20">
               <li>
                   <a>Submenu 1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a>Submenu 2</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
</details>
```

you may check it by expanding bottom padding of the parent container. Hope it helps